# Table is too wide

Tags: tables

I have inserted a table, but it is too wide compared to the text and the space between the bottom table and the next paragraph is too small. How could I fix that problem?

```
\section{Description}
\justify
In the implementation of the client-space, we must take 
into account registered and non-registered customers. Hence, 
on the home page of the current website \url{www.test.com},
we will insert two buttons in the upper right corner: 
\emph{Registration} and \emph{Login}.

The \emph{Registration} button will be a workflow by which the
customer will have to fill each step to place the first 
order and create a customer account. This workflow will
be done in three steps: \emph{Select Plan \& Preferences},
\emph{Personal Information} and \emph{Review \& Payment}.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Select Plan \& Preferences}}
 & First step of the workflow asking the customer to choose \\
 & the place of picking the order, the number of portions, \\
 & add products to his order if necessary and insert the date \\
 & and time of picking.\\
 \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Personal Information}}
 & Second step of the workflow asks the customer to enter \\
 & information about his/her place of residence, phone number \\  
 & and first and last name. \\ 
 \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Review \& Payment}}
 & Last step of the workflow by informing the customer of the \\ 
 & total amount of his order in Canadian dollars, requesting \\ 
 & payment information (Visa, MC, American Express) for the \\ 
 & order and additional information for the creation of a  \\ 
 & customer account. Knowing that the customer account is \\ 
 & created only if the order transaction has been accepted. \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

The \emph{Login} button will allow the customer to access
their client-space once they have placed their first order.
The client-space is built so that the customer can be aware
of the next order, see the history of the current and the 
next menus, see the history of all the orders, see the messages,
 modify the profile, place or modify an order and place a request 
for information if necessary.
```

Comment: Is there any reason for `\justify`?

Comment: @egreg Yes, I don't know why, but the alignment is center otherwise.

Comment: @Dave You probably have some improperly closed `center` somewhere.

Comment: @egreg You are right, I removed `\justify` and it is now fine. The table is still problematic

Comment: Sometimes, the things that matter are invisible to the beholder's eye. Please provide a compilable MWE, that reproduces your error and it shall be addressed properly in due time. Also, is there a reason for all those lines in the table? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\section{Description}

In the implementation of the client-space, we must take 
into account registered and non-registered customers. Hence, 
on the home page of the current website \url{www.test.com},
we will insert two buttons in the upper right corner: 
\emph{Registration} and \emph{Login}.

The \emph{Registration} button will be a workflow by which the
customer will have to fill each step to place the first 
order and create a customer account. This workflow will
be done in three steps: \emph{Select Plan \& Preferences},
\emph{Personal Information} and \emph{Review \& Payment}.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
\textbf{Select Plan \& Preferences} &
  First step of the workflow asking the customer to choose
  the place of picking the order, the number of portions,
  add products to his order if necessary and insert the date
  and time of picking.\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Personal Information} &
  Second step of the workflow asks the customer to enter
  information about his/her place of residence, phone number
  and first and last name. \\ 
\addlinespace
\textbf{Review \& Payment} &
  Last step of the workflow by informing the customer of the
  total amount of his order in Canadian dollars, requesting
  payment information (Visa, MC, American Express) for the
  order and additional information for the creation of a
  customer account. Knowing that the customer account is
  created only if the order transaction has been accepted. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

The \emph{Login} button will allow the customer to access
their client-space once they have placed their first order.
The client-space is built so that the customer can be aware
of the next order, see the history of the current and the 
next menus, see the history of all the orders, see the messages,
 modify the profile, place or modify an order and place a request 
for information if necessary. 

\end{document}
```

I took the opportunity of removing most of the table rules, that add nothing and actually hinder the interpretation of the table.

[image]

A possible improvement is making the first column narrower:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand{\firstcol}[1]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  #1
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Description}

In the implementation of the client-space, we must take 
into account registered and non-registered customers. Hence, 
on the home page of the current website \url{www.test.com},
we will insert two buttons in the upper right corner: 
\emph{Registration} and \emph{Login}.

The \emph{Registration} button will be a workflow by which the
customer will have to fill each step to place the first 
order and create a customer account. This workflow will
be done in three steps: \emph{Select Plan \& Preferences},
\emph{Personal Information} and \emph{Review \& Payment}.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
\firstcol{Select Plan \& \\ Preferences} &
  First step of the workflow asking the customer to choose
  the place of picking the order, the number of portions,
  add products to his order if necessary and insert the date
  and time of picking.\\
\addlinespace
\firstcol{Personal \\ Information} &
  Second step of the workflow asks the customer to enter
  information about his/her place of residence, phone number
  and first and last name. \\ 
\addlinespace
\firstcol{Review \& \\ Payment} &
  Last step of the workflow by informing the customer of the
  total amount of his order in Canadian dollars, requesting
  payment information (Visa, MC, American Express) for the
  order and additional information for the creation of a
  customer account. Knowing that the customer account is
  created only if the order transaction has been accepted. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

The \emph{Login} button will allow the customer to access
their client-space once they have placed their first order.
The client-space is built so that the customer can be aware
of the next order, see the history of the current and the 
next menus, see the history of all the orders, see the messages,
 modify the profile, place or modify an order and place a request 
for information if necessary. 

\end{document}
```

[image]