# Table for Technical Specifications

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am currently working on technical specifications for the purpose of building a client-space on a website. I need to estimate the time for each step of the creation. Hence, there are two sub-subject to consider: `Registration` and `Login`. So the idea is to create a single table, i.e. [Table is too wide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404500/table-is-too-wide), with the following information :

**Registration:**

1. Select Plan & Preferences --> 25 hours estimate
2. Personal information --> 25 hours estimate
3. Preview & Payment --> 25 hours estimate

**Login:**

1. Create dashboard --> 100 hours estimate
2. Create the client-space --> 20 hours estimate
3. Create 'My orders' --> 25 hours estimate
4. Create 'Messages' --> 40 hours estimate

How could I modify the following code so that It could be displayed on three columns? Or simply, how could I improve it so that it looks beautiful?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true, linkcolor=cyan
}

\newcommand{\firstcol}[1]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  #1
  \end{tabular}%
}

\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}
\begin{document}

\section{Schedule}

Here is an estimate of the time at each step for the creation of a client-space for the website \url{www.test.com}.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\toprule
\firstcol{Registration} &
 Select Plan \& Preferences : 25 hours estimate\\
 Personal information : 25 hours estimate\\
 Preview \& Payment : 25 hours estimate\\
\addlinespace
\firstcol{Login} &
 Create dashboard : 100 hours estimate\\
 Create the client-space : 20 hours estimate\\
 Create 'My orders' : 25 hours estimate\\
 Create 'Messages' : 40 hours estimate\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{images/}}
%\usepackage{parskip}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true, linkcolor=cyan
}

\newcommand{\firstcol}[1]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  #1
  \end{tabular}%
}

\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}
\begin{document}

\section{Schedule}

Here is an estimate of the time at each step for the creation of a client-space for the website \url{www.test.com}.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Creation Phase}} & \textbf{Estimaded Hours}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Inscription}} \\
 & Select Plan \& Preferences & 25\\
 & Personal information & 25\\
 & Preview \& Payment & 25\\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Connexion}} \\
 & Create dashboard & 100\\
 & Create the client-space & 20\\
 & Create 'My orders' & 25\\
 & Create 'Messages' & 40\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple question for you... Are you able to remove the '1' next to `Schedule`?

Comment: @Dave: Using `\section*{Schedule}`  will remove the numbering of the section.

Comment: Are you able to insert `(Including email managing and the newsletter)` below `Create 'Messages'?`

Comment: @Dave It's just like "Create `Messages`" or any other line.

Answer (score 5):

Another idea (without tables):

[image: mew]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{bchart}[step=10,max=100,width=.6\linewidth,plain]
\bclabel{\bfseries Creation Phase}
\smallskip
\bcbar[value=\em Inscription]{}
\smallskip
\bcbar[label=Select Plan \& Preferences]{25}
\bcbar[label=Personal information]{25}
\bcbar[label=Preview \& Payment]{25}
\smallskip
\bcbar[value=\em Login]{}
\smallskip
\bcbar[color=orange, label=Create dashboard]{100}
\bcbar[color=orange, label=Create the client-space]{20}
\bcbar[color=orange, label=Create 'My orders']{25}
\bcbar[color=orange, label=Create 'Messages' ]{40}
\bcxlabel{\bfseries Estimated Hours}
\end{bchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a bit late, but very nice answer Fran!!!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}XXr}\toprule
Registration&
 Select Plan \& Preferences & 25 hours estimate\\
& Personal information & 25 hours estimate\\
& Preview \& Payment & 25 hours estimate\\[1ex]
Login &
 Create dashboard & 100 hours estimate\\
& Create the client-space & 20 hours estimate\\
& Create `My orders' & 25 hours estimate\\
& Create `Messages' & 40 hours estimate\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```